# Can we evaluate a predicate at every object?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is it really possible to have something like $\forall x, P(x)$ ? For example in one of the definitions of equality : $\forall x, \forall y, x = y \iff (\forall P, P(x) \iff P(y))$ or in ZFC's axioms of comprehension : $\exists E, \forall x, x \in E \iff P(x)$.
In my understanding, $P(x)$ may not make sense for all $x$'s. For example, if $P(x) : ``\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \frac{dx}{dt}(t) > 2"$, evaluating $P$ at $x = \mathbb{N}$ does not seem to make sense. Am I missing something here or do we implicitly only consider predicates and objects that make sense together?

Comment: The really tricky part in your question is how you define "object" since it may refer to anything in its most generality philosophically speaking. In the early naive set theory, the existence of the absolute Russell set cannot be evaluated leading to the famous Russell paradox...

Comment: We "evaluate" a formula according to an interpretation. $\forall n \text {Even}(n)$ has a "definite" meaning when interpreted in the domain of *natural* numbers; not so in e.g. the domain of human beings.

Answer (score -2):

These statements are not made in a vacuum, there is always a context, and so $\forall$ always means "for all values in this particular context". In your example, the predicate $P(x)$ is defined on some domain of $x$, which is presumably something like "$x \in \mathbb{R}$".

Generally, when writing mathematical proofs, it is considered acceptable to remove explicit context where it should be generally understood, so if I already know that $P(x)$ is a predicate on the real numbers, then a statement like $\forall x P(x)$ is referring to only real values of $x$, not complex numbers or random objects or anything else.

Comment: This is misleading in the context of a question about the axioms of ZFC, which in fact do use "contextless" quantifiers.

Comment: I suppose it's tricky since the second part of the question is going into things that don't quite line up with that, but looking at it again, you're right and I will add something more specific about the contextless ones.

Comment: Although, thinking about it more, they're still talking about a domain of some kind, aren't they? $\forall P (P(x) \iff P(y))$ still implicitly requires that $P$ be a predicate, unless you accept that $P(x) \iff P(y)$ is considered true when $P(x)$ doesn't even make sense as long as $P(y)$ is equally meaningless.